# Unable to identify current week in excel as Previous, Current or Next week

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2013, excel-2016

I am trying to identify current week in excel. Tried `weekday` `weeknum` with different combinations but I am always getting somewhere or the other.

Assuming I have dates filled in range A1:A15 from 21-Nov-18 to 5-Dec-18. In column B after every corresponding cell, I wish to have two values "PW" "CW" and "NW" which stands for Previous week, Current week and Next week. How to use the `weekday` or any other formula to show the status in column B after every date from column A?

I think what I am going in the right direction but getting stuck somewhere where I am unable to figure out what would be the syntax to achieve desired result. PLease help

Desired solution is:
21-Nov to 25 Nov should have PW as status
26-Nov to 2-Dec should have CW as status
3-Dec to 5-Dec should have NW as status
My week starts on Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE((WEEKNUM(A1,2)-WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2)+2),"PW","CW","NW"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: wow! thats great ! so quick... i m impressed. One more question. If I only need to mark CW in that case, can this formula be shortened?

Comment: Then a standard IF: `=IF(WEEKNUM(A1,2)-WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2) = 0,"CW","")`

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to evaluate this formula to understand the logic. one last question... how did u post the excel sheet in the answer :)

Comment: @Sabha the `(WEEKNUM(A1,2)-WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2)+2)` will return the difference `...,-1,0,1,...`  We then add 2 to get the `-1` to equal `1`  The choose then chooses the correct return.  If it is not 1,2,3 then it errors and then we put in a blank.  As to posting I did a screen grab and posted as a picture.

Comment: wonderful logic. something which i didnt think of. have a great time Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you want to display 3 values: `"PW"`, `"CW"` or `"NW"`

I split the answer in two formulas, which can be combined in a single one, but this way is more clear:

B1: `=WEEKNUM(A1,2)-WEEKNUM(TODAY())`

C1: `=IF(B1<0,"PW",IF(B1=0,"CW","NW"))`

Column B has to be in "General" or "Number" format, but you can simply hide it.

[Screen capture in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXomC.png)

Comment: your results are off one day, OP wanted the week to start on Monday not Sunday.

Comment: Thanks for your time Edwin. Appreciate a lot

Comment: You're right Scott, I adjusted the formula to reflect Monday as the first day of the week. Thanks.

Comment: `WEEKNUM(TODAY())` needs also to be `WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2)` or you will be off a full week when TODAY is Monday.